# MySQL/MariaDB Server: Bind To 1 IP Address only

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

a noob question. how can i bind IP address 192.168.X.X only on Mariadb server, other says i should change the bind ip address 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in linux mariadb.conf.d but it will only allow other IP address to access the database server. i need help thanks in advance!

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

Comment: bind to the network address of 192.168... . Hopefully 'other IP' is on the same network. Alternately/Additionally use firewall rules to restrict traffic. Be specific on network addresses. They are private network addresses anyway so you're not really causing a vulnerability by disclosing them.

Comment: so ill just bind the IP address and add firewall rules to allow the certain IP address to use the traffic. Thank you! @danblack